# Custom ActionResult File Path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

When i try to do this:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string page)
    {
        IndexViewModel model = new IndexViewModel();
        return ("~/Themes/_Layout.cshtml", model);
    }
```

It gives me the error `The name 'model' does not exist in the current context` on the first line `@model InnodiaCMS.Models.Controllers.IndexViewModel`

But it all works fine when _Layout.cshtml is in the shared folder.

But i need it to be in Themes folder! How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the `<system.web.webPages.razor>` section from `~/Views/Web.config` to `~/Themes/Web.config`.

For more information, see [my blog post](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/02/dissecting-razor-part-3-razor-and-mvc.html).

Comment: Oh finily a problem in mvc that is easy to solve xD Thank you! And thank you for the link aswell.